# Error with Zustand and Typescript when using Persist. The Error is: persist.d.ts(95, 210): An argument for 'options' was not provided

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zustand

I'm trying to use the persist functionality using Zustand following the pattern on the Zustand documentation for Typescript but I get an error when I add the persist method.

The error is `persist.d.ts(95, 210): An argument for 'options' was not provided.`

Here is an example of the code producing the error:

```
import { create, StateCreator } from 'zustand';
import { devtools, persist } from 'zustand/middleware';
import { CountryData } from './countryTypes';

interface CountrySlice {
    countries: CountryData[];
    fetchCountries: () => void;
}

const countrySlice: StateCreator<CountrySlice> = (set) => ({
    countries: [],
    fetchCountries: async () => {
        const res = await fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all');
        set({ countries: await res.json() });
    },
});


export const useCountryStore = create<CountrySlice>()(
    persist(
        devtools((...a) => ({
            ...countrySlice(...a),
        }))
    )
);
```

What are these "options" I'm missing and where should they be included?

I tried finding documentation on this issue but haven't found anything that fixes the issue. The closest issue I found has a solution using a deprecated version of Zustand.

Comment: If you want to access the type for the options parameter you can do something like `type PersistOptions = Parameters<typeof persist>[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Provide options for `persist` (it's in the error; "persist.d.ts"):

```
export const useCountryStore = create<CountrySlice>()(
    persist(
        devtools((...a) => ({
            ...countrySlice(...a),
        })),
        { name: "my cool name" },
    )
);
```

The name is required.

See the docs: https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/integrations/persisting-store-data

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQGjgZRizQGF0to4BfOAMyghDgHIAvAVwGciA7AE2YBuALAAoUJFiI4fNADcYECABtOeMGiidg3anQZM2XXnwD0IYHz7K0AdwzohY06YACMTgFpgAcx7Q0OH94CWheGDFQqSQSCHYeGCgATwARLAw9ekYWADpTZDiE5IAVJI1OJ1FIhM1aDGRA2PjEpPxlYAbEMTgelELE4DROAC44JqLU9IBtAF0RUV66NBhkAAtxgaHRgAoASjgAXgA+ODkIS3mqMTECnl0C5uS2jrRRwmIyTEUoAB4Np-aDROBzg204y32x1BCG6vQeRUGIzgsxwsJ6tGWa3+iNGGE4SR4yFBkJOMIWizhEDu8HQnEOcAw9mA8AxK1W22YqxgMDAIxctJW-SgiJyBRApjkAGYcgBGUwYZTKZi7eYU3rgmDbJDwzZIxkYZlwWk5ABWnCpe2oKrR1FRoio1qqTrQAA9JPBbrouKQha1voEQagvmg-r7nkC9tsbRotDpNTbFrIFEpVNttjkMxgSdCE2q4BnRWHAWh05ndna81by7mekgeBgQK84AAiEBJPoqIINtDN2023ZiR1AA)

Comment: Wow... totally missed that. Thanks a lot vr.!